# SQL - select the lowest price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database with cars and all possible cars options with prices. I want to do car search by options. For example: I need a car with heated seats.

I have a problem with SQL query. I need to get a lowest price from cars options. In my table "cars_options" there are options and package e.g (climatronic, parking sensor, Package(parking sensor, heated seats).

When we looking for car with parking sensor the query should return all cars with parking sensor OR package with parking sensor with lowest price.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e1fb/1)

Climatronic:

```
VW Passat | 1000 // package with climatronic is too expensive
VW Golf| 1000 // package with climatronic is too expensive
```

Parking sensor AND Climatronic

```
VW Passat | 1400 // climatronic + parking sensor is too expensive (1500), package is cheaper
VW Golf| 1400 // golf has parking sensor only in package
```

The biggest problem is with packages, I don't know how can I check what is cheaper or what is more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table for the options in packages by the look of it.

Instead of linking to option e.g Climatronic, link to a package that is just climatronic, or one that has several options.

E.g 
Packages : CarId,PackageId, Price

Options : OptionId, OptionName

PackageOptions
PackageId,OptionId

Answer (score 0):

I second that idea of having a separate table for packages and link them to the options. For now may be this would help ( if I understand you correctly.)

```
SELECT c. name as "CAR", co.name "OPTION", co.price FROM CARS c
INNER JOIN CARS_HAS_OPTIONS cho ON c.id = cho. id_car
INNER JOIN CARS_OPTIONS co ON co.id = cho. id_car_option
WHERE co.name LIKE '%Parking sensor%'
ORDER BY PRICE ASC
```